# installing angular material throws an error

Tags: angular, material-design

after installing angular-material with this command

```
 npm install --save @angular/material @angular/animations @angular/cdk
```

I'm getting this error when i'm trying to run ng serve. 
it really weird because some days ago i did the same installation in other project and it works fine.
I'm trying for some hours to solve this issue but nothing really helpful.
I tried to remove the node modules and install again..

```
ERROR in E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClass/colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/material/typings/radio/radio.d.ts (134,44): Type '(new (...args: any[]) => CanColor) & (new (...args: a
ny[]) => CanDisableRipple) & typeof MdRadioB...' is not a constructor function type.

ERROR in E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClass/colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/material/typings/select/select.d.ts (8,76): Module '"E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClass/
colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'Renderer2'.

ERROR in E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClass/colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/material/typings/select/select.d.ts (8,114): Module '"E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClass
/colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'InjectionToken'.

ERROR in E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClass/colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/material/typings/select/select.d.ts (28,41): Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts.

ERROR in E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClass/colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/material/typings/select/select.d.ts (30,46): Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts.

ERROR in E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClass/colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/material/typings/select/select.d.ts (34,44): Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts.

ERROR in E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClass/colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/material/typings/select/select.d.ts (41,45): Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts.

ERROR in E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClass/colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/material/typings/select/select.d.ts (58,45): Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts.

ERROR in E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClass/colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/material/typings/select/select.d.ts (63,52): Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts.

ERROR in E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClass/colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/material/typings/select/select.d.ts (87,22): Class 'MdSelect' incorrectly implements interface 'CanColo
r'.
  Property 'color' is missing in type 'MdSelect'.

ERROR in E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClass/colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/material/typings/select/select.d.ts (87,22): Class 'MdSelect' incorrectly implements interface 'CanDisa
ble'.
  Property 'disabled' is missing in type 'MdSelect'.

ERROR in E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClass/colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/material/typings/select/select.d.ts (87,39): Type '(new (...args: any[]) => CanColor) & (new (...args:
any[]) => CanDisable) & typeof MdSelectBase' is not a constructor function type.

ERROR in E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClass/colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/material/typings/sidenav/sidenav.d.ts (8,65): Module '"E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClas
s/colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'Renderer2'.

ERROR in E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClass/colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/material/typings/slider/slider.d.ts (8,47): Module '"E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClass/
colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'Renderer2'.

ERROR in E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClass/colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/material/typings/slider/slider.d.ts (34,22): Class 'MdSlider' incorrectly implements interface 'CanDisa
ble'.
  Property 'disabled' is missing in type 'MdSlider'.

ERROR in E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClass/colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/material/typings/slider/slider.d.ts (34,39): Type '(new (...args: any[]) => CanDisable) & typeof MdSlid
erBase' is not a constructor function type.

ERROR in E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClass/colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/material/typings/slide-toggle/slide-toggle.d.ts (8,84): Module '"E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/A
ngularClass/colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'Renderer2'.

ERROR in E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClass/colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/material/typings/slide-toggle/slide-toggle.d.ts (28,22): Class 'MdSlideToggle' incorrectly implements i
nterface 'CanColor'.
  Property 'color' is missing in type 'MdSlideToggle'.

ERROR in E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClass/colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/material/typings/slide-toggle/slide-toggle.d.ts (28,22): Class 'MdSlideToggle' incorrectly implements i
nterface 'CanDisable'.
  Property 'disabled' is missing in type 'MdSlideToggle'.

ERROR in E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClass/colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/material/typings/slide-toggle/slide-toggle.d.ts (28,22): Class 'MdSlideToggle' incorrectly implements i
nterface 'CanDisableRipple'.
  Property 'disableRipple' is missing in type 'MdSlideToggle'.

ERROR in E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClass/colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/material/typings/slide-toggle/slide-toggle.d.ts (28,44): Type '(new (...args: any[]) => CanColor) & (ne
w (...args: any[]) => CanDisableRipple) & (new (...args: ...' is not a constructor function type.

ERROR in E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClass/colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/material/typings/snack-bar/snack-bar-config.d.ts (8,28): Module '"E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/
AngularClass/colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'InjectionToken'.

ERROR in E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClass/colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/material/typings/snack-bar/snack-bar-container.d.ts (8,43): Module '"E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular
 4/AngularClass/colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'Renderer2'.

ERROR in E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClass/colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/material/typings/snack-bar/snack-bar-container.d.ts (14,37): Initializers are not allowed in ambient co
ntexts.

ERROR in E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClass/colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/material/typings/snack-bar/snack-bar-container.d.ts (15,37): Initializers are not allowed in ambient co
ntexts.

ERROR in E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClass/colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/cdk/table/typings/cell.d.ts (8,22): Module '"E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClass/colorsNo
tes/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'Renderer2'.

ERROR in E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClass/colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/cdk/table/typings/row.d.ts (28,31): Type 'IterableDiffer' is not generic.

ERROR in E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClass/colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/cdk/table/typings/table.d.ts (8,69): Module '"E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClass/colorsN
otes/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'Renderer2'.

ERROR in E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClass/colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/cdk/table/typings/table.d.ts (8,80): Module '"E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClass/colorsN
otes/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'TrackByFunction'.

ERROR in E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClass/colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/material/typings/table/cell.d.ts (8,22): Module '"E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClass/col
orsNotes/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'Renderer2'.

ERROR in E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClass/colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/material/typings/tabs/tab.d.ts (17,22): Class 'MdTab' incorrectly implements interface 'CanDisable'.
  Property 'disabled' is missing in type 'MdTab'.

ERROR in E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClass/colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/material/typings/tabs/tab.d.ts (17,36): Type '(new (...args: any[]) => CanDisable) & typeof MdTabBase'
is not a constructor function type.

ERROR in E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClass/colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/material/typings/tabs/tab-group.d.ts (8,47): Module '"E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClass
/colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'Renderer2'.

ERROR in E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClass/colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/material/typings/tabs/tab-group.d.ts (32,22): Class 'MdTabGroup' incorrectly implements interface 'CanC
olor'.
  Property 'color' is missing in type 'MdTabGroup'.

ERROR in E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClass/colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/material/typings/tabs/tab-group.d.ts (32,22): Class 'MdTabGroup' incorrectly implements interface 'CanD
isableRipple'.
  Property 'disableRipple' is missing in type 'MdTabGroup'.

ERROR in E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClass/colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/material/typings/tabs/tab-group.d.ts (32,41): Type '(new (...args: any[]) => CanColor) & (new (...args:
 any[]) => CanDisableRipple) & typeof MdTabGro...' is not a constructor function type.

ERROR in E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClass/colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/material/typings/tabs/ink-bar.d.ts (8,10): Module '"E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClass/c
olorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'Renderer2'.

ERROR in E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClass/colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/material/typings/tabs/tab-label-wrapper.d.ts (18,22): Class 'MdTabLabelWrapper' incorrectly implements
interface 'CanDisable'.
  Property 'disabled' is missing in type 'MdTabLabelWrapper'.

ERROR in E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClass/colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/material/typings/tabs/tab-label-wrapper.d.ts (18,48): Type '(new (...args: any[]) => CanDisable) & type
of MdTabLabelWrapperBase' is not a constructor function type.

ERROR in E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClass/colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/material/typings/tabs/tab-header.d.ts (8,105): Module '"E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularCla
ss/colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'Renderer2'.

ERROR in E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClass/colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/material/typings/tabs/tab-header.d.ts (30,22): Class 'MdTabHeader' incorrectly implements interface 'Ca
nDisableRipple'.
  Property 'disableRipple' is missing in type 'MdTabHeader'.

ERROR in E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClass/colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/material/typings/tabs/tab-header.d.ts (30,42): Type '(new (...args: any[]) => CanDisableRipple) & typeo
f MdTabHeaderBase' is not a constructor function type.

ERROR in E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClass/colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/material/typings/tabs/tab-nav-bar/tab-nav-bar.d.ts (8,59): Module '"E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular
4/AngularClass/colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'Renderer2'.

ERROR in E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClass/colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/material/typings/tabs/tab-nav-bar/tab-nav-bar.d.ts (25,22): Class 'MdTabNav' incorrectly implements int
erface 'CanColor'.
  Property 'color' is missing in type 'MdTabNav'.

ERROR in E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClass/colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/material/typings/tabs/tab-nav-bar/tab-nav-bar.d.ts (25,39): Type '(new (...args: any[]) => CanColor) &
typeof MdTabNavBase' is not a constructor function type.

ERROR in E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClass/colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/material/typings/tabs/tab-nav-bar/tab-nav-bar.d.ts (55,22): Class 'MdTabLink' incorrectly implements in
terface 'CanDisable'.
  Property 'disabled' is missing in type 'MdTabLink'.

ERROR in E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClass/colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/material/typings/tabs/tab-nav-bar/tab-nav-bar.d.ts (55,40): Type '(new (...args: any[]) => CanDisable)
& typeof MdTabLinkBase' is not a constructor function type.

ERROR in E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClass/colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/material/typings/toolbar/toolbar.d.ts (8,22): Module '"E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClas
s/colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'Renderer2'.

ERROR in E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClass/colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/material/typings/toolbar/toolbar.d.ts (19,22): Class 'MdToolbar' incorrectly implements interface 'CanC
olor'.
  Property 'color' is missing in type 'MdToolbar'.

ERROR in E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClass/colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/material/typings/toolbar/toolbar.d.ts (19,40): Type '(new (...args: any[]) => CanColor) & typeof MdTool
barBase' is not a constructor function type.

ERROR in E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClass/colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/material/typings/tooltip/tooltip.d.ts (8,59): Module '"E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClas
s/colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'Renderer2'.

ERROR in E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClass/colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/material/typings/tooltip/tooltip.d.ts (8,89): Module '"E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClas
s/colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'InjectionToken'.

ERROR in E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClass/colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/material/typings/tooltip/tooltip.d.ts (17,42): Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts.

ERROR in E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClass/colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/material/typings/tooltip/tooltip.d.ts (19,41): Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts.

ERROR in E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClass/colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/material/typings/tooltip/tooltip.d.ts (21,42): Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts.

ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling function 'InjectionToken', function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an
 exported function, resolving symbol MD_AUTOCOMPLETE_SCROLL_STRATEGY in E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClass/colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/material/typings/index.d.ts, resolving s
ymbol MD_AUTOCOMPLETE_SCROLL_STRATEGY_PROVIDER in E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClass/colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/material/typings/index.d.ts, resolving symbol MdAutocompleteMo
dule in E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular 4/AngularClass/colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/material/typings/index.d.ts, resolving symbol MdAutocompleteModule in E:/פרוייקטים/פרוייקטים קיץ/Angular
 4/AngularClass/colorsNotes/node_modules/@angular/material/typings/index.d.ts
```

I'm trying also to import browserAnimationsModule but it shows me error in the path

```
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
```

Answer (score 0):

run npm update and see if it fixes your problem. If not, then delete your node modules folder and run npm install to reinstall all the modules.

Comment: Still not works. it shows me an error in this path import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

Comment: Did you delete your node_modules folder and run npm install?

Comment: Yes man, it shows error with material design and browserAnimationsModule. when I remove material and broswer the project works fine.